# Dynamic routing in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still new with AngularJs. The url is changing but the page is always the same. I'm looking forward for your help.

Config:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource','ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
             templateUrl: '../pages/.index1.html'

        })
    .when('/profile',{
         templateUrl: './profile.html'

    }).when('/messages',{
        templateUrl: 'file.html'
    });
 }]);
```

and here is my index1.html where i'm calling for app.js

```
<script src="../angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>
<ul>         
   <li class="">
      <a ng-href="#/"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Users</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a  ng-href="#/profile"><i class="icon-user-1"></i> Profile</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a ng-href="#/messages"><i class="icon-comment-fill-1"></i> Messages</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking.  What exactly is the difference between the current and desired behavior?

Comment: Did you name your your index page `.index.html` also why do you have `#` symbol before value in your `ng-href` attributes?

Comment: well .index.html is a mistake even without it it's not working and the # meant that I'm staying in the same page but adding #/profile for example

Comment: @KevinCrain angular default routing is done with a hash

Comment: paths to templates are inconsistent. Also do you have an `ng-view` element? That's where the templates get inserted. See docs

Comment: Actually no how and where can I add it ? I never used it before. Besides the tutorial I followed is not using ng-view !

Comment: it is very unlikely that a functional tutorial is demonstrating `$routeProvider` without an `ng-vew` HTML element.  The `$routeProvider` defines what to show, the `ng-view` defines where to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that all your HTML isn't included above, but in your full HTML file you need to define the location where the views for your routes will be injected. Perhaps you are missing that? There is a special directive called ng-view. You use it simply as:

```
 <div ng-view></div>
```

That div will then become the location where your views are displayed as you navigate through your app.

There is a full example in the angular docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example